# how to insert data into fields created at run time in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

it is possible to create column at run time in mysql table using add column in php.

but how to insert data at run time into the newly created field(s) (i.e.column(s))?

thanks in advance

***EDIT***:

some said that why i need to create a new column at run time as i know  before hand that the column will be necessary. No, columns quite unknown at the beginning may be needed to be created Just take the problem as a programming issue.

**PLZ GIVE THE EXPLANATION OF -VE  RATING**

i donno why my post was rated -ve ly. uff where is the solution to the prob that someone needs to create columns in a mysql table beforehand and the thing is quite unpredictable. Suppose a site admin needs to add column to a membership club table from time to time. Can't this be any real situation? Why is there no explanation of -ve rating , plz?

Comment: Could you please provide more info on how you intend to use this.

Comment: For example - why would you have a database that needs to do DDL operations at Runtime? As an aside - presumably your application knows what columns (names) it created, therefore why cant you know what columns you need to insert data into?

Comment: @user658911  suppose a 'student' table has 3 columns - id(primary key), name, roll_no. Now a 4th column address is necessary to be added by the admin of the site so that when the students log into the site next time, they will be prompted to provide the address info as well into their profile .

Comment: So it has nothing to do with columns created at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Oh that,

You know you need to create the address column already. Then what you need to do is do a 2 step registration.

You need to check whether this column is empty when the student logs in. If it is empty then you ask the student to put in their address. When they have typed in the address the just update the column and change it from blank to the address provided by the student. You dont need the dynamic columns as that would be slow and complex operation.

```
Check database for the address of the student or check if the user is loggin in the first time
If the users address is empty or the user is logging in the first time 
     Then
         Ask the user for their address
         If the address is given then
              Update the address column with the provided address
         Endif
Endif
```

Done

Comment: other columns may also be necessary to be created. Instead of looking at the environment, please look at  the programming issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute a MySQL command in PHP code to add a column, create a table, alter a table and more.

Comment: but how to insert data at run time into the newly created field(s) (i.e.column(s))?

Answer (score 0):

Use a function that alters your table and which returns true, if the altering was successfull. If you get this, you can use normal UPDATE functions.

But you should never, never, never design your application this way. Think about all the ibformations, that you will get now and in the future. Then design your tables referring to this informations.

In your special case you already know, that you will aks for the address informations, so implement this NOW in your code. user658911 showed you how to do this.

In the future it might be neccessary to add more columns or tables to your system, because the requirements will change. If so, you can realize those changes on your development system, test them with your current database content and after all deploy it to your production system.

Altering a table during runtime should never be an option.

Comment: nooo, i just stated a sample problem.. look at my 'edit' plz.